# Parse out First Name, Last Name from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering how to parse out the first name, last name from a fullname with also considering getting rid of middle name, Mr, Ms, and JR in the middle and JR at the end.

```
Jon Doe Jr  First: Jon  Last: Doe  
Jon J Doe   First: Jon  Last: Doe  
Mr Jon Doe  First: Jon  Last: Doe
```

Thank you

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions about what constitutes a name. There is no gaurantee that a name is simply `FIRST<space>MIDDLE<space>LAST` Many surnames contain several words. As far as I am aware there is no gauranteed algorithmic way to reliably parse a full name into given/surname.

Comment: International names can also have a reverse order which makes you confuse first and last name. Very embarrassing.

Comment: You also have former titles that are officially part of the last name now. You certainly do not want to strip them out!

Answer (score 0):

select left(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)) as first,
substring(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)+1, len(name)-(CHARINDEX(' ', name)-1)) as last
from table-name;

Comment: this can help you

Comment: any ideas of how to parse out the name by using sql server?

Comment: use above query@Rachel

Comment: substring_index is not supported by sql sever.

Comment: can u try to use above and if not working then reply me immediately beacuse i am active for two days full hours@Rachel

Answer (score 0):

I found a nifty Function called PARSE_NAME_UDF [here](http://fostersolutions.com/parsing-names-sql-server/)

I use this function from time to time in my data migration and integration work:

Here are a few examples that return two columns First and Last names:

```
  SELECT 'First:' = dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Jon Doe Jr', 'F'), 'Last:' = dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Jon Doe Jr', 'L')
      UNION ALL SELECT 'First:' = dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Jon J Doe', 'F'), 'Last:' = dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Jon J Doe', 'L')
      UNION ALL SELECT 'First:' = dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Jon Doe', 'F'), 'Last:' = dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Jon Doe', 'L')
```

Here are more examples:

```
  SELECT dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Fred J Muggs Jr', 'F M L S') -- Returns Fred J Muggs Junior
  SELECT dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Fred J Muggs Jr', 'F M L s') -- Returns Fred J Muggs Jr
  SELECT dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF('Fred J Muggs Jr', 'f. M. L s') -- Returns F. J. Muggs Jr
```